# How could I write the content of a array of pointers to a file using fwrite?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
void write(const record* list[])
   {
        FILE* out=fopen("output.txt","w");
        if(!out)
        {
            printf("error"); exit(1);
        }else
        {

        }
   }
```

fwrite takes a array as the first argument, but my array is a array of pointers. I want the content of the pointer pointing to written to the file. How could I manage it?

Comment: Loop through the top-level array and call `fwrite` with each pointer.

Comment: then what fopen mode should I use? appending one?

Comment: Only if you're closing and re-opening around each call. Otherwise, just the regular "w"rite mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  fwrite(list[i], sizeof (record), 1, out) ;
}
```

where `length` is the size of the array. You must modify your program and pass the length to your `write` function.

Comment: what fopen mode should I use? appending?

Comment: fopen("output.txt","a");